# String replace with regexp overwrites non matching character

Tags: javascript, regex

The idea is replacing in a string all decimal numbers without a digit before the decimal point with the zero so `.03 sqrt(.02)` would become `0.03 sqrt(0.02)`.

See the code below for a sample, the problem is that the replacement overwrites the opening parenthesis when there's one preceding the decimal point. I think that the parenthesis does not pertain to the matching string, does it?

```js
let s='.05 sqrt(.005) another(.33) thisShouldntChange(a.b) neither(3.4)'

s=s.replace(/(?:^|\D)\.(\d+)/g , "0.$1");

console.log(s)
```

Comment: For clarity, please use backticks, not boldface, to call out inline code.

Comment: Use `s.replace(/(^|\D)\.(\d+)/g , "$10.$2")`

Comment: You do not have to put `\D`, a single token, into a character class, `[\D]` = `\D`.

Comment: @Wiktor, good point thanks. I will edit to make clearer the main point in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your initial group capturing, not non-capturing, and use it in the replacement:

```
s=s.replace(/(^|[^\d])\.(\d+)/g , "$10.$2");
//           ^---- capturing, not non-capturing
```

Example:

```js
let s = '.05 sqrt(.005) another(.33) thisShouldntChange(a.b) neither(3.4)'

s=s.replace(/(^|[^\d])\.(\d+)/g , "$10.$2");

console.log(s)
```

> I think that the parenthesis does not pertain to the matching string, does it?

It does, because it matches `[^\d]`.

---

Side note: [As Wiktor points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50154264/string-replace-with-regexp-overwrites-non-matching-character#comment87326015_50154264), you can use `\D` instead of `[^\d]`.

---

Side note 2: JavaScript regexes are finally getting [lookbehind](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-regexp-lookbehind) (in the [living specification](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-assertion), and will be in the ES2018 spec snapshot), so an alternate way to do this with **modern** JavaScript environments would be a negative lookbehind:

```
s=s.replace(/(?<!\d)\.(\d+)/g , "0.$1");
//           ^^^^^^^--- negative lookbehind for a digit
```

That means basically "If there's a digit here, don't match." (There's also *positive* lookbehind, `(?<=...)`.)

Example:

```js
let s = '.05 sqrt(.005) another(.33) thisShouldntChange(a.b) neither(3.4)'

s=s.replace(/(?<!\d)\.(\d+)/g , "0.$1");

console.log(s)
```

Answer (score 1):

A parenthesis is a nn-digit, thus it is matched with `[^\d]` and removed.

The solution is to match and capture the part before a dot and then insert back using a replacement backreference.

Use

```
.replace(/(^|\D)\.(\d+)/g , "$10.$2")
```

See the [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/0k28ks/1).

**Pattern details**

- `(^|\D)` - Capturing group 1 (later referred to with `$1` from the replacement pattern): a start of string or any non-digit (`[^\d]` = `\D`)
- `\.` - a dot
- `(\d+)`  - Capturing group 2 (later referred to with `$2` from the replacement pattern): 1+ digits.

See the JS demo:

```js
let s='.05 sqrt(.005) another(.33) thisShouldnt(a.b) neither(3.4)'

s=s.replace(/(^|\D)\.(\d+)/g , "$10.$2");

console.log(s)
```

Note that `$10.$2` will be parsed by the RegExp engine as `$1` backreference, then `0.` text and then `$2` backreference, since there are only 2 capturing groups in the pattern, there are no 10 capturing groups and thus `$10` will not be considered as a valid token in the replacement pattern.